# AMP update-cache resulting in 404 or 410 error from origin

Tags: caching, amp-html

I've been trying to update the AMP cached pages on my website for a couple of days now to no avail.

While the documentation for updating the cache exists, it was probably written by a Google engineer, and as a result, isn't the easiest read.

> https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/update-cache

I've followed the directions to the best of my ability.
I've created a private-key and public-key. Created a signature.bin and verified it using the procedure in Google's own documentation.

> ~$ openssl dgst -sha256 -signature signature.bin -verify
>   public-key.pem url.txt
>
> Verified OK

The public-key.pem has been renamed to apikey.pub and uploaded to the following directory:

> https://irecover.ca/.well-known/amphtml/apikey.pub

To validate that there has been no issue in the copying, I checked the signature using the following:

> $ openssl dgst -sha256 -signature signature.bin -verify <(curl https://irecover.ca/.well-known/amphtml/apikey.pub) url.txt
>
> % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time
>   Current
>
> Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
>
> 100   450  100   450    0     0   2653      0 --:--:-- --:--:--
>   --:--:--  2662
>
> Verified OK

Now I convert the signature file to base64 and replace the / with _ and the + with -

> cat signature.bin | base64 > signature.b64
>
> sed 's///_/g' signature.b64 > signature.b64a
>
> sed 's/+/-/g' signature.b64a > signature.b64b
>
> sed 's/=//g' signature.b64b > signature.b64c
>
> cat signature.b64c | tr -d '\n' > signature.b64

I have made a script that makes the update-cache url for me. It also creates a timestamp right that moment and uses it for the amp_ts variable (So the amp_ts is never out by more than 1 second). I then append that to the end of the query which is about to be cURL'd by the script I have made, so it looks like so:

> https://irecover-ca.cdn.ampproject.org/update-cache/c/s/irecover.ca/article?amp_action=flush&amp_ts=1581446499&amp_url_signature=KDaKbX0AbVbllwkTpDMFPOsFCRNw2sbk6Vd552bbG3u5QrecEmQ1SoMzmMR7iSXinO7LfM2bRCgJ1aD4y2cCayzrQuICrGz6b_PH7gKpo6tqETz06WmVeiP89xh_pBOu-pyN5rRHf0Pbu8oRkD2lRqgnGrLXDfIrFTTMRmHlO0bsa8GknyXL8RNXxk9ZQaufXAz-UJpoKaZBvT6hJWREAzxoZ-rGnDPVaC3nlBCu3yPorFcTbbr0CBz2svbfGgAYLQl54lLQmUpxI8661AEe1rdOLqAyLIUb4ZiSbO65-PmIkdZWVPFHMdbpSv4GMNdvodleCWBfMAcG2C09v-LR6g

However, this always results in the same error code from google.

> Invalid public key due to ingestion error: 404 or 410 error from origin

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: They ask to serve the key with the content-type "text/plain" in the Guidelines section in the docs you provide. Maybe this is important for them for some reason. You serve your key without content-type. You can check this in Network panel in your browser.

Comment: @JamesGray did changing the content-type help you? I and many others online seem to be struggling with this topic. In my case at least I have set the content-type

Comment: Hi, is it solved? I was also confused about cache update and got good idea from bug reported over amphtml repo here is link - https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/20959

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to check for apikey.pub accessibility:

1. The `/.well-known/amphtml/apikey.pub` file is accessible to both mobile and desktop user agents (e.g no redirect for non-mobile as the AMP cache client may redirect)
2. The public key is not excluded in robots.txt e.g:

```
    User-agent: *
    Allow: /.well-known/amphtml/apikey.pub
```

3. The public key response has the expected headers (e.g content-type: text/plain):

```
    curl -I https://amp.example.com/.well-known/amphtml/apikey.pub
    
    HTTP/2 200 
    date: Sun, 26 Jul 2020 23:48:55 GMT
    content-type: text/plain
    vary: Accept-Encoding
    etag: W/"1c3-173478a8840"
    last-modified: Sun, 26 Jul 2020 23:48:55 GMT
```

With those things in place, I get an "OK" success response from the update/cache endpoint

[image: AMP update cache OK response]